# Is it possible to acces Servlet object in a filter?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

Is it possible to acces Servlet object in a filter? Not object that is in servlet but **servlet** object.

Comment: What kind of filter? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Normal filter, that implements Filter interface

Comment: Why do you want to do it? Please explain your use case.

Comment: Well try giving the question some context, tell us what you have tried, add relevant links that you have found. This will make it easier to help you, and you will more likely be up voted (or at least not down voted, cause now it looks like a poor question)

Comment: I hava around 30 servlets and i want to make easy access control. I want to servlets implement interface with methods that will return requied roles to work with this servlet and validate that in filter.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are asking about servlet filter. The answer is "no". You cannot access servlet from either other servlet or filter.

Once upon a time there was such API somewhere in servlet context but it was deprectated about 15 years ago since java designers decided that servlet (and also filters) are independent components managed by servlet container and accessible via HTTP only.

You can obviously implement some kind of work around. For example since servlet continer typically creates only one instance of servlet you can store this instance in static variable of servlet itself and then access it from either filter or other servlet. However this technique smells bad for a lot of reasons.

It will be nice if you can explain *why* do you want this. Probably community can help you to find better solution.

EDIT

Since you explained your reason I can suggest you to use JMX to implement this task. JMX is designed for management of java components and your task is pure management.